# make middle span with ellipsis without breaking icon and right number

Tags: html, css

I want to add **ellipsis** to `li.text` but at the same time I want to preserve right `span` (with numbers) and distance (padding) between number `span` and `text` span.

How can I make this happen?

```css
.right {
  float: right;
  padding: 0 8px;
}

.menu {
  width: 155px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  list-style-type: none;
}

body {
  font-family: "Segoe UI", "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none
}
    .p {
     width: 155px;

      white-space: nowrap; 
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      display: inline-flex;
    }
      .text {
        white-space: nowrap; 
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        width: 45%;
        padding-right: 16px;
      }
      .right {
        width: 10%;
      }
```

```html
<link href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="menu">
 <li class="" data-action="switchFolder" data-sign-in="false" id="inbox">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">
            <div class="p">
      <i class="icon ion-ios-filing-outline"></i>
      <span class="text">This is a very long element that wil exceed limit</span>
      <span class="right">429</span>
            </div>
  </a>
 </li> 
</ul>
```

Expected result:

[image: result]

Attention to the space between `429` and `text`. I tried few but it seems it comes to near of 429. Also whatever I try it broke to next line due to icon.

Comment: What solutions have you tried so far?

Comment: I have updated code according to my attempt. I cover them inside a `div` but i think this is not the right thing. This is why i didn't post what I tried at first. Look at how 429 located. It isn't located at right but based on text data. I want to make sure 429 is on the right and there is a space between text and number.

Comment: `margin-left: auto;` on the number ?

Comment: margin makes no difference still not aligned well

Comment: `.text {width :100%}`, no? Also remove width from the `.right`

Comment: This worked. number get aligned to right. However, it break the icon-text position. I will try to fix on my side manually.

Comment: Add `.text {padding-left: 5px}` for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you are using `inline-flex`, the `100%` width should work perfectly for achieving what you need:

```
.text {
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.right {
  width: 10%; /* remove it */
}
```

```css
.right {
  float: right;
  padding: 0 8px;
}

.menu {
  width: 155px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  list-style-type: none;
}

body {
  font-family: "Segoe UI", "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none
}
    .p {
     width: 155px;

      white-space: nowrap; 
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      display: inline-flex;
    }
      .text {
        white-space: nowrap; 
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        width: 100%;
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 16px;
      }
      .right {
        /*width: 10%;*/
      }
```

```html
<link href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="menu">
 <li class="" data-action="switchFolder" data-sign-in="false" id="inbox">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">
            <div class="p">
      <i class="icon ion-ios-filing-outline"></i>
      <span class="text">This is a very long element that wil exceed limit</span>
      <span class="right">429</span>
            </div>
  </a>
 </li> 
</ul>
```